# put a list inside a panel/container

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I want to put a simple list into a panel or a container but doesn't work, I can see the titleBar but not the list.. this is the code:

(this Container is inside a TabPanel)

```
Ext.define("PrimaProva.view.ClientList", {
    extend: "Ext.Container",
    xtype: 'clientlist',
    //fullscreen: true,


    config: {
        title    : 'Gsrid',
    iconCls: 'user',

        items: [
    {
        xtype: 'titlebar',
        docked: 'top',
        title: 'Clients List'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'list',
        store: 'Grid',
        itemTpl: '{text}',
    }
    ]
     },
});
```

As you can see it is very easy…
the store "Grid" is absolutely not a problem because it works in another view….
Anyways this is the code:

```
Ext.define('PrimaProva.store.Grid', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',

   requires : [
        'PrimaProva.model.Grid'
    ],

config : {
    model : 'PrimaProva.model.Grid',
    data  : [
        { text : 'One',   amount : 1  },
        { text : 'Two',   amount : 2  },
        { text : 'Three', amount : 3  },
        { text : 'Four',  amount : 4  },
        { text : 'Five',  amount : 5  },
        { text : 'Six',   amount : 6  },
        { text : 'Seven', amount : 7  },
        { text : 'Eight', amount : 8  },
        { text : 'Nine',  amount : 9  },
        { text : 'Ten',   amount : 10 }
    ],
groupField: 'text', 
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
layout: 'fit',
fullscreen: true,
```

to the config of your ClientList

Working Fiddle: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#onlHz

Comment: Please accept the answer ;) I think it's necessary because the container doesn't know how to render the list. When you set the height of the list (for example: height: 400,) then you don't need to specify the layout